# Footer Background appearing twice in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/services has the footer background appearing twice in what appears all versions of IE.  I've checked the HTML and the footer element seems to be appearing twice in the HTML of IE but not in Chrome.

I'm unclear on why this is happening as I don't recall putting the code in there twice and I would think that it would show up in Chrome as well if I had.  I've used a markup validator to check the page and it says that I'm missing a whole bunch of opening and closing tags (which are actually there when I look at the code).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: If you cannot find a solution, you could put <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE7" /> in your header as a temporary fix.

Comment: Always trust the [online HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).  You [missed something](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com%2Fservices&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 2):

At the footer, there are two anchor tags `<a>` are not closed. Fix that and your problem will be solved.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DpGyT/1/

Change

```
<div class="lbtns">
<a href="http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/contact-us"><img src="http://www.uvhc.mikeandjewels.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/images/mapsbtn.png">
</div>
<div class="lbtns">
<a href="http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/patient-forms"><img src="http://www.uvhc.mikeandjewels.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/images/frmsbtn.png">
</div>
```

To

```
<div class="lbtns">
    <a href="http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/contact-us"><img src="http://www.uvhc.mikeandjewels.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/images/mapsbtn.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="lbtns">
    <a href="http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/patient-forms"><img src="http://www.uvhc.mikeandjewels.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_185/custom/images/frmsbtn.png"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<a href="http://www.utahvalleyhealthclinic.com/patient-forms">
```

Apparently you didn't close it and something broke.

Try inspecting with IE (F12) and looking at the code at the same time to find what happened wrong.

Basically IE understood that you have two "footer" DIVs, though Chrome shows there's only one.

As for the closing TAGs, take care with the self-closing ones like `<br />` instead of `<br>` and `<img ... />` instead of `<img ...>`

Try something like NetBeans and use Auto-Indent (Or Google other ptions). Helps a LOT to find tags you forgot to close and see if everything's where it should.